# Visual Studio 2010 Premium Edition: Missing editor features

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In VS 2010 Premium, I've noticed that when I open the context menu, I don't see a way to access the call hierarchy.

[image]

How do I enable the feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Visual Basic?  Microsoft lists that its [only available in C# and C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409859.aspx).

Comment: Alas! You are right.